# How to set background color for UIWebView in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, colors, uiwebview, background

I have added the back ground color as an image to uiwebview but it is coming to the back side of web view not to the web view. The web view is always in white colored view, I can't change it.

```
myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
myView.autoresizingMask=YES;

webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BG_Doctor.png"]];

webView.delegate = self;
[myView addSubview:webView];
self.view=myView;
```

Please help me to set the background color to webview not to back of it

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[webView setOpaque:NO];

Comment: Or uncheck Drawing: Opaque in StoryBoard

Answer (score 3):

A webview will display a document, so background color is really nothing that makes a lot of sense here. If you want to display something while no page is loaded, build a placeholder page containing your background.

Comment: But you can see the background color when the webview is bouncing

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display a specific background before the UIWebView has loaded HTML content you can add a loading view over the top and then remove it when you get *webViewDidFinishLoad* on your *UIWebViewDelegate*:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

If you need to set the background color on the UIWebView once it has loaded the content, then you would do this in the HTML/CSS markup:

```
"background-color: #026dec;"
```